# Update notification context text using Notification.Builder

Tags: android

I was using "setLatestEventInfo" to update my notifications context text. But now, this method is deprecated, and documentation says I should use Notification.Builder to do this. I don't know how to use it to update my notification context text, or progress. Can you help me please?

I created the notification using Notification.Builder, but I don't know how to update once it's created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No answers... So I answer it myself: I can update the original Notification using the same Notification.Builder objet I used for creating the original one. Seems to work ok.